# Git History VSC does not show additional info about Renamed file and TortoiseGit does

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, tortoisegit, git-log

I have installed Git History extension in Visual Studio Code, and use it pretty often, as it provides pretty nice overview of how repo changes over the time and commits. What I noticed recently is lack of additional info about file which has been renamed. I am comparing it to with TortoiseGit.

Let's have a look at example:

[[image: git_log_GitHistory_vs_TortoiseGit.png]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bxWD.png)

As you can see TortoiseGit provides additional info that `image_get_image.h` has been renamed from `image.h` and 3 lines have been added/removed. I do not see similar info from Git History from VSC, only when I hover the green/red squares the info appears about added 3 & deleted 3, nothing about the name of original file name, which seems to be quite important.
Any tips how to tune the Git History from VSC to be able to see what the original file name was?

Comment: Hello,

Are those changes staged or not?

As far I know only staged delete/added changes will appear as renamed in git bash.

Comment: Hi, all changes are commited, so no changes pending to stage. Working tree clean

Comment: The Git History extension obviously follows renames when showing history, but does not print the original file name. Renaming is indicated only by the R icon. I think you should file an issue at the plugin's GitHub page in you need this feature: https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode/issues